# Email-ext notification subject changing

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, email-notifications

I have Jenkins configured and I'm using `Email-ext plugin` for email notifications. I'm sending Email messages every time I have my build broken.

So the question is:
Is there any chance to change default email subject - **Build failed in Jenkins: TestName #BuildNumber** ?

I've performed the next steps:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

[image]

So is there actually any way to change it? Or add something to it?

Comment: Forgive me for asking the obvious, but have you tried changing the Default Subject (right there where you have listed "I DON'T WANT TO SEE THIS..."?

Comment: @tkosinski I actually did it on the screenshot. I set subject to "I DONT WANT TO SEE THIS ...". But I got the message with the default one, like on the second and third screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go in the advanced section and to trigger this kind of trigger:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please confirm it solved your issue :)

Comment: At least this is not working for me i ve set different subjects for each trigguer but the email is being receiven in the same email thread without the new subject